# Serverless cannot read the default value for stage even though I specified one

Tags: serverless-framework

Hi when i tried to `serverless config` it returned an error `Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable ${opt:stage}. Please make sure the value of the property is a string.` However in my yml file I have specified a default value for stage:

```
 service: ''
    custom:
      prefixName: ''
      basePath: ''
      stagesPath: '${self:custom.basePath}config/stages'
      env: ${file(${self:custom.stagesPath}/${self:provider.stage}/env.yml)}
      baseUrl: ''
      warmup:
        schedule: 'cron(0/5 * ? * MON-FRI *)' # Run WarmUP every 5 minutes Mon-Fri
        prewarm: true # Run WarmUp immediately after a deployment
      prune:
        automatic: true
        number: 10
      appSync:
        - ${file(${self:custom.stagesPath}/${self:provider.stage}/appsyncUnaMe.yml)}
        # - ${file(${self:custom.stagesPath}/${self:provider.stage}/appsyncUnaCloudFeeds.yml)}
    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs8.10
      role:  ${self:custom.env.role}
      stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
      region: ${self:custom.env.region}
      vpc: ${self:custom.env.vpc}
      profile: ${self:custom.env.profile}
      environment: 
        APPSYNC_UNAME_API_X_API_KEY: ${opt:appsyncKey}
        APPSYNC_UNAME_API_X_URI: ${opt:appsyncUri}
        STAGE_NAME: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
        SERVICE_NAME: ${self:custom.prefixName}
      timeout: 10
      deploymentBucket: ${self:custom.env.deploymentBucket}
      versionFunctions: false
    package:
      individually: true
      exclude:
        - ".*/**"
    plugins:
      # - serverless-webpack
      - serverless-plugin-warmup
      - serverless-prune-plugin
      - serverless-appsync-plugin
      - serverless-offline

    functions:
      ${file(${self:custom.stagesPath}/${self:provider.stage}/resolvers1.yml)}
```

OS:                     darwin
     Node Version:           8.11.1
     Serverless Version:     1.27.3

Why is is showing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the other one.

```
environment:
  STAGE_NAME: ${opt:stage}
```

Comment: still having the same error. tracing the yml is really a headache.